# Why is the upper bound for a type field lost after a cast (see example in description)?

Tags: scala, types

After defining the following :

```
abstract class A {
  type T
  def print(p: T) = println(p.toString)
}

trait B extends A {
  type T <: String
}
```

As expected, we **can not** create an object with `T = Int` :

```
scala> val a = new A with B {type T = Int}
<console>:9: error: overriding type T in trait B with bounds >: Nothing <: String;
 type T has incompatible type
       val a = new A with B {type T = Int}
                                  ^
```

As expected, we **can** create an object with `T = String`:

```
scala> val a = new A with B {type T = String}
a: A with B{type T = String} = $anon$1@692dec

scala> a.print("test")
test
```

After casting our value `a` to the type `A with B`, we get an error when calling the `print` method. It seems the type field `T` lost its information about the type (?).

```
scala> val b = a.asInstanceOf[A with B]
b: A with B = $anon$1@1927275

scala> b.print("test")
<console>:15: error: type mismatch;
 found   : java.lang.String("test")
 required: b.T
              b.print("test")
                      ^
```

**Question 1:** Why is the information about the type field `T` lost after the cast ?

Okay, so we try it again with a cast which explicitly sets the type field `T` to a `String` type:

```
scala> val c = a.asInstanceOf[A with B {type T = String}]
c: A with B{type T = String} = $anon$1@1927275

scala> c.print("test")
test
```

Okay, this works - good.

Now let's try something crazy:

```
scala> val d = a.asInstanceOf[A with B {type T = Int}]
d: A with T{type T = Int} = $anon$1@1927275

scala> d.print(3)
3
```

**Question 2:** Huh ? Trait `B` restricted type `T` to be a subtype of String, but now the `print` method works with integers. Why is this working ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Question 1** — "After casting our value a to the type A with B, we get an error when calling the print method." What information about `T` is there after the cast? It is precisely what is in `B`:

`type T <: String`

Therefore the type is *not known*, just its upper bound. The following shows why the `print` call for `A with B` is forbidden:

```
trait X
trait Y extends X { def hallo() = () }

trait A {
  type T
  def test(t: T) = ()
}

trait B extends A {
  type T <: X
}

val y = new A with B { type T = Y; override def test(t: T): Unit = t.hallo() }
y.test(new X {})     // refused -- rightfully
y.test(new Y {})     // ok

val yc = y: A with B // note how we can cast type safe this way!
yc.test(new X {})    // refused -- rightfully (would try to call inexistent 'hallo')
```

So it's a problem of what can happen to types occurring in contravariant (method argument) positions. Had you defined `B` by narrowing the *lower bound*, i.e. `type T >: X`, it would be possible to call `test` even if `T` was not fixed.

---

**Question 2** — Of course it works. You can make the compiler allow any call with the type casting. After you cast to `A with B {type T = Int}`, you force the compiler to accept that `T = Int`. Now the `toString` method you call is defined for `java.lang.Object`, and due to the generic structure of `A`, your `Int` is boxed into a `java.lang.Integer`, and therefore you do not witness any runtime problem when calling `toString`.

But it is wrong to think that you are doing something correct here. For example:

```
abstract class A {
  type T
  def print(p: T) = println(p.toString)
}

trait B extends A {
  type T <: String
  override def print(p: T) = println(p.toUpperCase) // !
}

val a = new A with B { type T = String }
val b = a.asInstanceOf[A with B { type T = Int }]
b.print(33)  // bang -- runtime class cast exception
```

Comment: may you give more detailed example for *question 1*? `String` have `toString` method but `X` have no `hallo` method, so `B extends A { T <: String}` from topic is not equal for `B extends A { T <: X}`

Comment: "Question 2 — Of course it works. You can make the compiler allow any call with the type casting." - I don't get this. It is not the cast that is the issue here, but that `A with B {type T = Int}` is considered a legal type expression in the first place. Obviously, specialising an abstract type in a way that violates its bound is unsound, so the type system should better not allow it. The fact that your example only observes this with a cast does not matter. Note in particular that it is not the cast that is failing (weird as well, presumably to do with erasure), but a later operation.

Comment: @Andreas - what is the difference between that cast and `"Schoko".asInstanceOf[Int]*33`?

Comment: @ayvango - it's not `String` that has `toString` but `java.lang.Object`. That is the only reason why `print` could have been defined in `A`. The clue is `val yc = y: A with B`, so `A with B` is a super-type of `A with B { type T = Fixed }`. `T` may appear in a contravariant position (as a method argument), therefore the actual object `y` may call a method defined for `Fixed` (e.g. `hallo`) on an argument of type `T` passed into one of its methods (e.g. `test`). Consequently, when you have type `A with B` and `T` is _not fixed_, you can't just use `T`'s upper bound for `T`.

Comment: @Sciss: Thank you. Answer 1 accepted. But Answer 2 leads me to the question why the compiler does not complain about a such senseless cast, since the compiler knows the upper bound of `T` ? He also complains (correctly) about a cast like "test".asInstanceOf[Int]".

Comment: @John - that's the idea of casting, you overrule the compiler. Should be used with great care; allows things like re-using objects (the compiler would have to complain there, too!), one of the big up-sides of JVM type erasure. Of course in this particular case _you_ can analyse the code and say the cast is wrong, but to ask that of the compiler means it has to add a lot of complexity and heuristics. You could equally argue that the type inference should include more heuristics. `asInstanceOf` is just that: compiler _must_ accept.

Comment: @John - "He also complains (correctly) about a cast like "test".asInstanceOf[Int]" -- no, _it_ doesn't. It produces a runtime exception. _Because_ of the type erasure, a cast like `List("hallo").asInstanceOf[List[Int]]` does not immediately result in a runtime exception -- the JVM just sees erased type `List[_]`. You'll get the exception as soon as you try to operate on an element (try `.map(_+1)`).

Comment: @Sciss: The difference is that `Int` is a perfectly valid type. But `A with B {type T = Int}` isn't. It is self-contradictory and thus ill-formed. No values with this type can legally exist, cast or not. I am not talking about precluding nonsensical _casts_, I am talking about precluding nonsensical _types_. A nonsensical type should never be legal, no matter whether it appears in a cast or elsewhere.

Comment: @Sciss: Additional question: You mentioned a type safe cast like `val yc = y: A with B` in your code. How is this type safe construct called ? Where can I read more about it (it is hard to google something like that).

Comment: @John - In the [types documentation](http://docs.scala-lang.org/style/types.html) this is called _Ascription_. I didn't know that, thought it was something like 'explicit type annotation', but that text reserves the term _Annotation_ for other uses.

Comment: @Andreas - Well again there is a limitation of how far the compiler looks. Types can be constructed quite liberally, it seems the strong checking is rather done on the _use site_. For instance, you can write `def test[A](x: A { type T = Int }) {}`, and indeed it makes sense, even if there maybe types for which the method cannot be invoked.

Comment: @Sciss: Looking at the Scala spec again, it basically treats mixins as a kind of intersection type, which explains the limited checking to some extent. Practically, I don't see how an inconsistent type ever makes sense, though. What would it be useful for in your opinion?

Comment: I agree, I don't see any case where it would be useful. But it's also not harmful, you can't do anything with those declarations.

Answer (score 2):

> Question 1: Why is the information about the type field T lost after the cast ?

Because why you did a cast? A cast means: Hey compiler, it's me the omnipotent programmer. I want to do something what you do not understand. Do it - without contradiction!

And this is what the compiler does - it erases all his knowledge because that's it what you told him.

A type member is some compile time information and if you delete it with your cast you delete also the knowledge of the compiler.

> Question 2: [...] Why is this working ?

Because you are the omnipotent programmer and the compiler obeys. It has no chance to prove if it is correct what you tell him.

Ok, the last sentence is not completely true because our smart compiler knows that a programmer can never be omnipotent - even if one believes this. Therefore it does not always trust the programmer. It plays his own game and follows his own rules in order to protect the programmer. But even our compiler is not omnipotent. Sometimes it must trust the programmers instructions - as it is the case with most casts.

Comment: Thank you for your (somehow funny) explanation. :-)
I agree with Answer 1. And I see that the compiler accepts the cast in Question 2, because I told him to do so. But I was wondering, why the cast is allowed, because the (smart) compiler should know that trait `B` has an upper bound set for the abstract type `T` and therefore it makes no sense at all to cast `T` to an `Int` ? It's like the compiler does not allow me to do `"compilerIsSmatEnough".asInstanceOf[Int]`.